# How to read gmail imap mail content

Tags: php, imap

```
<?php

$stuff = fsockopen('ssl://imap.gmail.com',993);
$reply = fgets($stuff,4096);
echo 'connection: '.$reply.'<br/>';

$request = fputs($stuff,"a1 LOGIN ozgununlu91@gmail.com password\r\n");
$receive = fgets($stuff, 4096);

echo 'login: '.$receive.'<br/>';
$request = fputs($stuff,"a2 LIST '' '*'\r\n");
$response= fgets($stuff, 1024);
echo $response . "<br />";

$request = fputs($stuff,"a3 EXAMINE INBOX\r\n");
$response = '';
$end_of_response = false;
while(!$end_of_response){
$response.= fgets($stuff, 1024);
if(preg_match("/a3 (OK|NO|BAD)/", $response, $responsecode))
 $end_of_response = true;
}
print_r( $response);
echo "<br />";
$request = fputs($stuff, "a4 FETCH 1 BODY[]\r\n");
$response = fgets($stuff, 1024);
echo $response. "<br />";

?>
```

Output :

```
connection: * OK Gimap ready for requests from 95.9.132.93 n45if17443282eef.165 
login: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH 
a1 OK ozgununlu91@gmail.com Ozgun Unlu authenticated (Success) 
a2 OK Success * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen) * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Flags permitted. * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs valid. * 63 EXISTS * 0 RECENT * OK [UIDNEXT 135] Predicted next UID. * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 25549] a3 OK [READ-ONLY] INBOX selected. (Success) 
* 1 FETCH (BODY[] {7098}
```

i used same commands on this site ;
http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/imap.shtml

but after ( * 1 FETCH (BODY[] {7098} ) this line, i couldn't see my mails content.

NOTE: I don't want to use imap_list command, i should do it by this way.

Comment: Your content is on the next line, for the next 7098 bytes.

Comment: how can i do? can u give me an example?

Comment: Google your way to victory http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

Comment: Have you tried just logging in with a SSL enabled telnet tool (such as `socat` or `openssl s_client` to see what the protocol flow looks like?  Socket programming can be somewhat subtle, and being able to debug with a known good tool can help you quite a bit.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using raw sockets instead of PHP's built-in IMAP functions?